# Google Maps API V3 KML layer does not show up

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, overlay, kml, kmz

I followed many tutorials online but have not been successful in trying to get a google map window on my site with a desired KML overlay on it. My code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false">
</script>

<script>
function initialize()
{
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(38,-79.5),
    zoom:3,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
 }
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapOptions);
var overlay = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://doc-08-4g-       docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ckoh7mm1pf9l58sknv61gkpp19v37j15/r3rh37mucb8nscl1r37disrlcom7i93t/1372536000000/00236509183910004089/00236509183910004089/0B-qVNYv_qM5vNy1ZbzJYVUgtTjA?h=16653014193614665626&e=download');

overlay.setMap(map);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="googleMap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I dont understand the script src and why it's needed but I found it in the tutorials so i included it. As of now my KMZ and not KML file is in google drive which is open for the public and i have used the download link. This does not work even when I use KML files from examples in the internet.Am I missing something? Please Help!!

Comment: I'm not able to open the file (even if I remove the whitespaces from the URL)...so it doesn't seem to be public accessible. However, #googleMap needs a height when you want to see anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 issues I see:

1. the initialize function is never called
2. the map has no size
3. the KML is not valid (returns status INVALID_DOCUMENT)

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false">
   </script>

   <script>
   function initialize()
   {
   var mapOptions = {
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(38,-79.5),
       zoom:3,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }
   var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapOptions);
   var overlay = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://doc-08-4g-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ckoh7mm1pf9l58sknv61gkpp19v37j15/r3rh37mucb8nscl1r37disrlcom7i93t/1372536000000/00236509183910004089/00236509183910004089/0B-qVNYv_qM5vNy1ZbzJYVUgtTjA?h=16653014193614665626&e=download');

   overlay.setMap(map);
   google.maps.event.addListener(overlay,'status_changed',function(){
     document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = overlay.getStatus();
   });
     }
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load', initialize);
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="googleMap" style="height:500px;width:600px;"></div>
   <div id="status"></div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the code..I was trying to have the KML file on my Google Drive and have made it public. Would you know how to set that up?Or would Dropbox be a better option?Or even having the map on another part of the site itself?

Comment: @Ravin Looks like, currently, you can go to your KML in Google Drive, click in "File -> Embed", and there you'll get the javascript line with an url suitable to KmlLayer embedding, for example `var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({driveFileId: "0B2u_mC9PEAxyZDk1NjI4YjgtMzA5NC00ZDg3LTg3YzQtYTU5YTZmNjcyNTM1"
});` which is the same hashcode that appears in all types of GDrive URLs for that given file.

Answer (score 0):

google maps javascript API, KML layer,  limit the KML size to 10MB.
Over 10MB, you will get invalid document status on kmllayer object.

Your KML must first load to google KML service, than return back the tiled image to you.
Therefore your KML size must less than 10MB.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#restrictions

[image]